# selecting dictionary values corresponding to a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type -

```
{
 'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 'diff': [-3.654748632042965, -3.97342251742816, -4.010696955187965, -6.3903113605617685, -6.310284875983931, -4.0363808384515005],
 'b': [-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1]
}
```

I want to select `a` and `b` values corresponding to the minimum 'diff', which in this case should be [1,-1] corresponding to -6.3903. I am new to python and can't figure this out!

Comment: Can you be more specific? I did not understand your question. What are you trying to do? What did you try? And what results did you get?

Comment: how comes [1,-1]  as results?

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear. So if the minimum of 'diff' is the 4th value (-6.3903), then I want the 4th value to be returned from 'a'(1) and 'b'(-1) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `min` to find minimum of a list and then `index` to find the index of the minimum element and then take the elements of the corresponding index from `a` and `b`

```
d={'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'diff': [-3.654748632042965, -3.97342251742816, -4.010696955187965, -6.3903113605617685, -6.310284875983931, -4.0363808384515005], 'b': [-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1]}
a=d['a']
b=d['b']
diff=d['diff']
index=diff.index(min(diff))
print([a[index],b[index]])
```

OUTPUT

```
[1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [numpy.argmin()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html)

```
import numpy as np

d = {'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'diff': [-3.654748632042965, -3.97342251742816, -4.010696955187965, -6.3903113605617685, -6.310284875983931, -4.0363808384515005], 'b': [-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1]}

ind = np.argmin(d["diff"])

a = d["a"][ind]
b = d["b"][ind]

print([a, b])
```

**OUT:**

```
[1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple if you know how to deal with dictionary. This is my sample code in python:

```
def diff(dict):
    min = 0
    position = 0
    for index in range(len(dict["diff"])):
        checkValue = dict["diff"][index]
        if (checkValue < min):
            min = checkValue
            position = index
    print([dict["a"][position],dict["b"][position]])
```

### Test:

```
diff({'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'diff': [-3.654748632042965, -3.97342251742816, -4.010696955187965, -6.3903113605617685, -6.310284875983931, -4.0363808384515005], 'b': [-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1]})
```

Output:

[1,-1]

Comment: I am not too well versed with them. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: yeah, there are many ways to solve a problem, especially in python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min` with `zip` unpacking:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a, diff_min, b = min(zip(*itemgetter('a', 'diff', 'b')(d)), key=itemgetter(1))

print(a, diff_min, b)

1 -6.3903113605617685 -1
```